# app crashes due to map kit with MKReverseGeocoder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, locationmanager

I don't understand why this is crashing, whenever i came back to home page this app crashes, I have a file LocationSelectViewController.m when enabling zombie it throws an error

```
[LocationSelectViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x27b96740
```

Let me share a crash log

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b2665d0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   MapKit                          0x343b7492 -[MKReverseGeocoder _notifyResult:] + 70
2   ProtocolBuffer                  0x389631b6 -[PBRequester connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 1042
3   Foundation                      0x33eac912 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 14
4   Foundation                      0x33dec764 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 196
5   Foundation                      0x33dec680 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
6   CFNetwork                       0x3324d64c ___delegate_didFinishLoading_block_invoke_0 + 24
7   CFNetwork                       0x3324cd30 ___withDelegateAsync_block_invoke_0 + 52
8   CFNetwork                       0x33275010 ___performAsync_block_invoke_068 + 16
9   CoreFoundation                  0x334b6aca CFArrayApplyFunction + 174
10  CFNetwork                       0x3327546e RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 70
11  CFNetwork                       0x331d945e MultiplexerSource::perform() + 186
12  CoreFoundation                  0x335458f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
13  CoreFoundation                  0x33545158 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
14  CoreFoundation                  0x33543f2a __CFRunLoopRun + 642
15  CoreFoundation                  0x334b7238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
16  CoreFoundation                  0x334b70c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
17  GraphicsServices                0x37096336 GSEventRunModal + 70
18  UIKit                           0x353d32b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
19  PlanetTran                      0x000af534 0xae000 + 5428
20  PlanetTran                      0x000af4cc 0xae000 + 5324

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b74f5d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b68ad22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b686374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert your application in ARC(Automatic reference counting).
message sent to deallocated instance means you are trying to send the message that object is destroyed Automatically so you are getting this exceptions.
For converting in ARC goto Xcode
Edit->Refactor->convert to objective c ARC